# Exporting tooltip in excel from SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, tooltip

I have an SSRS report in which we are showing comments in tooltip but we are unable to get the same(tooltip in excel) when we export to excel using the inbuilt functionality of exporting in SSRS.

Any good code link or suggestion would be great help. Unable to find anything that I could implement.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, this [isn't possible (yet)](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/404285/ssrs-export-tooltips-to-excel-as-comments) in SSRS.

Your only option is probably to create a [custom rendering extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606.aspx) which is a *heavyweight* solution.